# Why would toolbar at bottom be too tall?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have several view controllers (each containing tableviews) embedded in a tool bar controller.  For some reason in one of them, the toolbar is higher by about double than in all the other view controllers.  I can't figure out what could be causing this. This particular VC does have a searchdisplay in it at the top but don't see why that would mess things up at the bottom.  In storyboard the tableview goes all the way to the bottom. Has anyone run across this problem before?

Here is a pic of the overly large tool bar.[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you post all of the code that touches this view's `frame`, its layout constraints, and its layout settings in your storyboard?

Comment: There are no constraints.. at least I cleared them so there should be none now.  I should mention that the segues from this view i.e. the detail page has the same issue.  With respect to layout settings, which ones are you interested in?